# Codificar string introducido por el usuario a uft-8 e ISO-8859-1

Tags: java

Necesito codificar strings introducidos por el usuario a uft-8 e ISO-8859-1. Solo me saca el string que introduce el usuario, por ejemplo si introduce `ú` debe devolver `Ãº` en ISO-8859-1.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce una palabra: ");

    String convertirUTF8 = new String(new_text.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    String convertirISO88591 = new String(new_text.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1");
          
    System.out.println(convertirUTF8 + "-" + "UTF8");
    System.out.println(convertirISO88591 + "-" + "ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: ¿Y que se supone que esperes como resultado? La cadena es la misma sea cual sea la codificacion.

Comment: Bienvenido, aporta mayor informaciòn, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, puedes poner un ejemplo del String que introduces? saludos.

Comment: Buenos días y gracias por las respuesta, ya he editado la pregunta poniendo un ejemplo de un string y lo que debe devolver. Gracias y saludos!